# taskIdentifier getting error [Swift]

Tags: ios, google-maps

This is my code below.

```
var placesTask = NSURLSessionDataTask()

func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, types:[String], completion: (([GooglePlace]) -> Void)) -> ()
  {
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=\(apiKey)&location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true"
    let typesString = types.count > 0 ? types.joinWithSeparator("|") : "food"
    urlString += "&types=\(typesString)"
    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    if placesTask.taskIdentifier > 0 && placesTask.state == .Running {
      placesTask.cancel()
    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
      var placesArray = [GooglePlace]()
      if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[])) as? NSDictionary {
        if let results = json["results"] as? NSArray {
          for rawPlace:AnyObject in results {
            let place = GooglePlace(dictionary: rawPlace as! NSDictionary, acceptedTypes: types)
            placesArray.append(place)
            if let reference = place.photoReference {
              self.fetchPhotoFromReference(reference) { image in
                place.photo = image
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(placesArray)
      }
    }
    placesTask.resume()
  }
```

The error I m getting:

> -[NSURLSessionDataTask taskIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8eba441e60
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[NSURLSessionDataTask
>   taskIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f8eba441e60'

I m not sure which part of the code went wrong. I tried to google and used the example code, but the error keep coming. Not sure if it's because of Xcode 7 beta 6

Comment: Where do you declare, and set up, the variable `placesTask`?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the reply. I declare it at the top. I have edited my post

Comment: Runs fine with Xcode 6.4, the property is available from iOs 7.0 which is required for Swift so that should not be a problem either. What happens if you alt+click or cmnd+click the property ?

Comment: @A-Live it shows the property. I tried to find solution online but doesn't seems to work

Comment: @Vimlan.G This is from my Google Maps tutorial. an updated version will be uploaded by tomorrow

Comment: This code doesn't work any more for XCode 8 for the line declaring place, let place = GooglePlace(dictionary: rawPlace as! NSDictionary, acceptedTypes: types) 
Swift 2.2 returns the following error message : Type '(key: String, value: AnyObject )' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Comment: this is the changed code to swift 2.2:
 if let results = json["results"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
          for rawPlace:AnyObject in results {
            let place = GooglePlace(dictionary: rawPlace as! [String:AnyObject], acceptedTypes: types)
            placesArray.append(place)

Answer (score 1):

The task must be created by a session.

var placesTask = NSURLSessionDataTask() is invalid